# How can I specify a cursor type for a recordset in pyodbc?

Tags: python, adodb, pyodbc

I am struggling with Python scripts that use the ADODB classes via COM.  I have concluded that the pyodbc module will be better for my purposes.  However, there are options available in the ADODB.Recordset.Open() method that I do not see in pyodbc.

ADODB.Recordset.Open() takes five arguments: a query string, a database connections, the cursor type, the lock type, and a bitmask of text and execute options.  Typically, we specify a dynamic cursor (cursor type 2), optimistic locking (lock type 3) and query string with no special execute options (option value 1).  There is another option not controlled in the Open() method: cursor location.  Before calling Open(), the recordset's CursorLocation property can be set to adUseServer (value unknown) or adUseClient (3, if I remember correctly).

While I know of no instance in any code my company has ever written where it is likely to matter, it would still be good to be able to make these choices through pyodbc.  Where would those choices be made?

Comment: I'm actually using this, and trying to move from COM to pyodbc as well.